# Tkinter Label not appearing

Tags: python, python-3.x, user-interface, tkinter

I am making a game for a raspberry pi with a 10inch touch screen, I have decided to use Tkinter to be able to interact with the pi.
Currently once the user has selected their game mode, and they are taken to this screen, I then try and place a label on this screen showing their current level, the code runs, tkinter window stops responding however code in the commandline continues.
Here is the code that is ran on the Survival Screen:

```
def start_survival(game):
    while game.health != 0:  
        print(str(game.level))#for Testing

        lbl = Label(root, text=lbBlue, font=SMALL_BUTTON_FONT)
        lbl['text'] = 'level: ' + str(game.level)
        lbl.place(x=35, y=15)
        print('Where is: ' + str(game.newDistance())+ ' and allowance is: ' + str(game.allowance))

        #game.newDistance()
        #count down
        game.measureDistance()
        if game.playerDistance >= game.lowerBound() and game.playerDistance <= game.upperBound():
            game.level += 1
            print('NEXT LEVEL')
        else:
            game.health -= 1
            print('Ouch! You just lost a life your health is now: ' + str(game.health))
            #u guessed ..... which is not in the range ..... ---->  little diagram
        game.allowance = int(game.allowance*0.90)

        if game.allowance > 5:
            game.allowance = int(game.allowance*0.90)
```

So all of the above is called from:

```
game = gamemode_normal()
root.after(100, lambda: start_survival(game))
```

If anyone has any ideas on what might be the problem, please share!
Thank you, Tom

Comment: The label appears when I stop the program with controll C or if I enter random values so that I loose all my lives

Comment: I do not think you should be calling a while loop every 1/10 of a second like this. once the while statement begins it will check the value of `game.health` on its own each loop it makes. You may need to rework how this function is written to avoid creating many while statements over and over again.

Comment: @SierraMountainTech: I don't see how it's called every 1/10th of a second. It looks to be called exactly once, 1/10th of a second after the code finishes initializing. It's still fundamentally broken, though.

Comment: game.measureDistance() is from def measureDistance(self):

       
        self.playerDistance = float(input("Guess a distance: ")) meaning that it doesnt loop rapidly, it loops every time a distance has been measured but in this case for testing it loops every time the user has entered something.

Comment: Okay so I just added 'root.update()' after where the lbl is placed and it looks like this has fixed the issue, it was a random guess with random words and it looks like this has fixed it, anyone got any other ideas why this might have been the case?

Comment: @BryanOakley I know that `root.after` is inside of another function because I helped him on another question he had. Though you are correct. After reviewing the other question again I do not see anything that shows the function is called multiple times. I must have been seeing things.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to update the display after placing the label, as your code is still running. Without manually running `root.update()`, Tkinter waits for your code to finish before updating the contents of the display. That's why it appears when you end the program with Ctrl-C. Here is the new code:

```
def start_survival(game):
    while game.health != 0:  
        print(str(game.level))#for Testing

        lbl = Label(root, text=lbBlue, font=SMALL_BUTTON_FONT)
        lbl['text'] = 'level: ' + str(game.level)
        lbl.place(x=35, y=15)
        root.update()
        print('Where is: ' + str(game.newDistance())+ ' and allowance is: ' + str(game.allowance))

        #game.newDistance()
        #count down
        game.measureDistance()
        if game.playerDistance >= game.lowerBound() and game.playerDistance <= game.upperBound():
            game.level += 1
            print('NEXT LEVEL')
        else:
            game.health -= 1
            print('Ouch! You just lost a life your health is now: ' + str(game.health))
            #u guessed ..... which is not in the range ..... ---->  little diagram
        game.allowance = int(game.allowance*0.90)

        if game.allowance > 5:
            game.allowance = int(game.allowance*0.90)
```

---

Many people confuse the `update` function with the `mainloop` function. The difference between these two functions is that the `mainloop` function *blocks*, meaning that it doesn't allow the code to continue running after it is called - by running an infinite loop inside the function. However the `update` function runs the loop only the amount of times needed to display everything, then ends and continues your code.

Answer (score 0):

maybe you should try to do `lbl.pack()` under the defining of lbl. Usually it helps